# Postfix error logs with random emails on my domain

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I was trying to figure out why my MySQL service keeps crashing, and a quick look at the logs shows hundreds of postfix errors like this:

```
postfix/smtpd[59256]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[84.76.126.109]: 450 4.1.1 <CathyRidgway@genyx.co.uk>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table; from=<byLandeykrNugena@outlook.c$
```

and

```
postfix/smtpd[59256]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[188.123.107.254]: 450 4.1.1 <MaryLittle-Nelson@genyx.co.uk>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table; from=<suStongevoqoJoellen$
```

I have no idea who these people are? Are they from a bot generating random names? How can I stop it, there are thousands of them!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why MySQL would crash because of these errors, but yes, a bot or other automated spammer is probably targetting your domain.

You could try using greylisting to slow down or scare off spammers.

Here is an howto to enable greylisting for postfix on Ubuntu, many more can be found for other distro's. It is a somewhat technical change to make, you could mess up your ability to receive e-mail, so please be careful.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixGreylisting

Comment: I have installed it and test my email is still working so I'll see over the next few days if it has worked thanks!
The mysql bit was just because I was looking for mysql errors but the had been pushed off the end of the file because of all these postfix errors